# HTML video opacity transition Chrome issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, html5-video

I've encountered an "issue" when trying to fade-in / out a video using a CSS transition on opacity. After the transition is done, the video flickers for a fraction of a second. This effect only occurs in Chrome, it's working properly in other browsers. You can see a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/bx2ar546/1/

After you click the button for the transition in, the flicker occurs at the end of the animation.

The relevant CSS:

```
video { width:640px; height:360px; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; transition:opacity 1s ease-out; }
video:not(.active) { opacity:0; transition-duration:.5s; }
```

Does anyone know if there is a workaround for this?

Comment: I don’t see anything flicker in Chrome.